# Convert mixed markdown/yaml/latex to docx

Tags: pandoc

I'm trying to convert a markdown file to docx using pandoc. In particular, my markdown file makes use of YAML and LaTEX syntax (I use markdown as much as possible for simplicity). This is the document sample:

```
% Title

---
author: Name
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{cleveref}
toc-title: Content
---

# Heading

See \cref{image}.

![Image caption\label{image}](image.png)
```

If I run `pandoc source.md -o output.docx --table-of-contents` it does not render appropriately the `\cref{image}`. However, if I convert it to PDF (`pandoc source.md -o output.pdf  --table-of-contents`) it does; but then other Markdown syntax (e.g. `[see @citation]`) does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't `pandoc` require you to give a bibliography command (e.g., `--biblatex` or `--natbib`)?

Comment: Yep in order to use citations I use `--bibliography`, but here I wanted to focus on how to implement latex pure commands (which I need for example to render the list of figures) with plain markdown text (that is a lot easier for example when it come to tables rendering)

Comment: Hmm, well, I think `pandoc-to-docx` questions are off-topic for this site, so the only part of the question that fits is the one about the bibliography. And it sounds like you know how to make `@citation` work..? (As an aside, I do not really know anything about `to-docx` conversions.)

Comment: Ouch ok then I opened a ticket [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3470). Thanks for your help.

Comment: For converting to PDF are you using `--filter=pandoc-citeproc`?

Comment: @AlexanderVonMoll I am trying to convert to .docx

Answer (score 2):

These are two questions. It takes some time to get used to the proper syntax,  you seem to get the yaml a little off (remember to refer to the [user manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) frequently). So here we go:

1. **Picture does not get printed in the pdf.** This happens because pandoc usually does not understand plain latex within the markdown unless the -s flag is passed. So if you want this image to get rendered in both pdf and docx you need to use proper pandoc syntax: `![la lune](lalune.jpg "Voyage to the moon")`. Remove the \label{image} part. If you want a label, you will need to pass the flag --filter pandoc-crossref. The syntax also changes slightly to accept the label: `![Caption](file.ext){#fig:label}`
2. **Citation is not picked up by pandoc.** Here you have some problems, first you have to point to a bibtex file in the yaml. The syntax is `bibliography: '/file.bib'`. Second you have to pass another flag  `--filter pandoc-citeproc` to pandoc. Third, use @citation to refer to it.

Finally, your md should look more like:

```
---
title: Title
author: Name
toc-title: Content
bibliography: '/file.bib'
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{cleveref}
---

# Heading

See @fig:label. This dude has talked about it previously: @thedude2017

![Caption](file.ext){#fig:label}

# References
```

Build it with `pandoc file.md --filter pandoc-crossref --filter pandoc-citeproc -o file.pdf`.